# ¿Cómo agrupo varias barras de Chart.js si el mismo label tiene mas filas?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, chart.js

Explicando un poco, tengo una consulta donde tomo el nombre del usuario, y el curso al que se encuentra inscrito más el avance o progreso del mismo.
Pero pasa que puede estar inscrito a más cursos, esto generaría otra barra y repetiría el mismo nombre, quisiera agrupar dicho estudiante y que me muestre barras múltiples, anexo el script:

```
<script>
                        var ctx = document.getElementById('chart2').getContext('2d');
                        var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'horizontalBar',
                        data: {
                            labels: [<?php echo $nombre_usuario;?>],
                            datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Progreso %',
                                data: [<?php echo $porcentaje;?>],
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.8)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.8)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.8)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.8)'
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 2
                            },]
                        },
                        options: {
                            legend:{
                                display:false
                            },
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true,
                                        stepSize: 10
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    </script>
```